# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.[table_name]" does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, name="Id")
    private BigInteger id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private TableB tableB;
    
    //Setters Getters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, name="Id")
    private BigInteger id;
    
    //Setters Getters
}
```

Then the following interface and controller to create the corresponding db records:

```
public interface TableARepository extends CrudRepository<TableA, BigInteger>{}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@PostMapping(value="/CreateTableA") 
public void createTableA(@RequestParam String something){
    TableB tableB = new TableB();
    TableA tableA = new TableA();
    tableA.setTableB(tableB);
    
    TableARepository.save(tableA);
}
```

I have also declared my schema at the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.tableA" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding below line to your application.properties file
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: This generates the following error on startup: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: identity column type must be smallint, integer, or bigint. But all my IDs are BigInteger.

Comment: You have to use long in java in place of bigint

Comment: As long represents bigint in sql

Comment: Also, change it to Long here
`public interface TableARepository extends CrudRepository<TableA, Long>{`

Comment: and in your entity too. Change it to long from BigInteger